# Is it possible to close gitlab merge request by Jenkins when build fails

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

It works like this now,somebody creates a merge request in gitlab which triggers a build in Jenkins through “Trigger builds remotely”,jenkins implements the defined build and does something after the build(Post-build Actions).
There's an option called "Accept gitlab merge request on success" in the "Post-build Actions" in jenkins jobs,but we want to implement "Close/Delete gitlab merge request on failure" after a failed build,is this possible please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible. I think this is because most people don't want to do it. Just because the build fails doesn't mean that your merge request is invalid. You can keep your merge request open, fix up the code and keep running builds until the build is successful, and your merge request will keep on being updated with the latest checkins. Then once it builds you can accept the merge request instead of churning and constantly creating new ones which is where you would end up.